# Can we get a graphic design?

Tags: discussion, support, site-promotion, design

I've been planning on making a business card I can hand out (and pass around the design) for **rpg.stackexchange.com**.  I can setup all the text I want, but it still looks plain.  Could someone design a simple graphic for the site?

**Note:** This is not expected to be permanent, but something we can use for advertising the site in beta.

Comment: I suppose each design should be an answer and we vote for the best?

Comment: We can absolutely do that @BBischof.

Answer (score 9):

I've always thought that a d20 is a really good representation of role-playing games.

[image]

This image has the 'Don't-need-a-license-'cause-I-drew-it-and-you-can-have-it' license.
I cranked this out very quickly.  If there is interest in it, I can take the time to do a better version.

Comment: So would anyone be against it if i printed this out and put it on a flyer to hang up at a game shop?

Comment: @DForck42, I'm ok with it, but you should get the ok from the stackexchange guys.

Comment: A d20 is a better metaphor for RPGs than a d6, because a) it's always been one of the most important dice in D&D and it's derivatives and therefore historically linked to rpgs, and b) the d6 is more commonly associated with board and dice games than rpgs.

Comment: Why would you put the 1 as the predominant side, your evil you are!

Answer (score 7):

I like @Iain M Norman's one, with the question mark.

Here's something similar, using some [Wikimedia commons dice](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Dice_%28PSF%29.png) instead of the paid stock art (and notably cheaper-looking as a consequence :P)

[image]

Tossed in part of the [Stack Exchange logo](https://stackapps.com/questions/347/svg-versions-of-the-logos), but I'm not a lawyer and don't understand if that's allowed according to the [Stack Apps Legal Page](https://stackapps.com/legal/trademark-guidance).

Here's another with more StackExchange branding borrowed/stolen:

[image]

Comment: I like having the address in an address bar. Nice touch.

Comment: Given the legal, I would say not.  I asked for clarification [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65298/16487)

Comment: +1 Incorporating a bit of stackexchange is nice

Answer (score 4):

As a stop gap feel free to use this:

[image]

Is this covered by the CC-wiki license? I've used paid for stock art, so my license wouldn't extend to anyone else reselling it, that's all.

I think that no matter what the site ends up being called, the D6 is near perfect for our question and answer site!

Comment: Can we get a link to the license for that image? IANAL, but I'd be interested in digging into the license to see what we can and can't do with it. It really is a perfect image.

Comment: It's purchased under a standard license at the moment. http://www.istockphoto.com/license_comparison.php

Comment: Ah. So as purchased it's prohibited by: 4.4 use any of the Content as part of a trade-mark, design-mark, trade-name, business name, service mark, or logo

Comment: Last point here: http://www.istockphoto.com/article_view.php?ID=616

Comment: Oh well seems I'll have to redraw something similar.

Comment: Ross you can use this for advertising purposes perfectly fine though, just not as part of a logo.

Comment: OK, like I said this isn't official,  just wanted something shiny to pass out.

Comment: FYI: Pdf link in chat [here](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/195081#195081)